# Making active link with php and bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need a little help with my code. I'm using bootstrap and i have 3 links for now and i want them to be active as i click on them. I tried many ways to do that but i failed.

Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">POSLOVNA STATISTIKA</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <li class="active"><a href="index.php?poslovni_korisnici">Poslovni korisnici <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?korisnici">Korisnici</a></li>   

        </ul>            
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li <?php if(isset($_GET['poslovni_korisnici'])){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="index.php?poslovni_korisnici">Poslovni korisnici <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li <?php if(isset($_GET['korisnici'])){ echo 'class="active"'; } ?><a href="index.php?korisnici">Korisnici</a></li>   
</ul>
```